# Is Android + PhoneGap/Cordova always a headache?

Tags: android, cordova

I've been developing a mobile app for both iOS and Android.  Due to time/budget constraints, we initially selected PhoneGap/Cordova as mobile app framework so we could write once and deploy to both platforms.

This plan has worked fine for iOS, but we're finding that Android's browser/engine is kind-of a piece of garbage (to put it nicely).  Every time we add a new feature, we find one more thing that the Android browser doesn't support, or only partially supports, or fully supports but will randomly fail from time to time, etc.  Even once we code around the Android issues and get things working smoothly, test it on multiple devices/versions, and deploy a new app to the Android market, we immediately start getting emails and reports from customers who can't get the app to work on their device. We have them uninstall/reinstall, reboot their phone to clear the memory, etc., and their device still consistently fails (and by "fail", I mean it typically just freezes and/or won't respond to touch input - it usually doesn't crash, or anything).  The app works fine for most people, but there are still quite a few devices that inexplicably fail.

I don't mean for this to be a rant, I'm trying to analyze whether the Android+PhoneGap path is the correct path for us.  Specifically, I'd like to find out the following:

1. Are there people out there having success with an Android+PhoneGap app? or is Android+PhoneGap always going to be a problem on certain devices?
2. Am I likely to have more luck with a native Android app (I've never attempted one)? Or are multiple devices/versions always a problem on Android, even with a Native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having worked with Android+Cordova for some time now, I have the following suggestions/comments for anyone thinking of going that direction.

1. Consider using Sencha Touch, or jQuery Mobile, or another mobile framework that has already coded around the Android-browser issues (which there are a LOT of).  Consider not straying too far from the default styling that come with those frameworks. Simply styling a normal web page to look like a mobile app is a constant headache to get working on multiple versions of the stock Android browser.
2. Although the stock Android browser is garbage, Mobile Chrome is pretty nice. In Android 4.4, the Chrome engine becomes the default engine used by a webview of an Android app. If you don't like Sencha or jQuery Mobile or the like, you could hold off and just use a mobile web site for a while until Android 4.3 and below become insignificant.  It's not hard to get things working on Mobile Chrome.
3. Even without Sencha/JQM, you can still muscle your way around the stock browser issues, but it's almost as frustrating as developing for IE6. Okay, maybe not that bad… but close.
4. I've started experimenting some with a native Android app, and, so far, it seems like less of a headache than building an app with Android+Cordova+lackOfSenchaOrJQMorTheLike.  The things I've experimented with work pretty consistently among different Android versions.  But I don't have much experience there, so I can't comment too much on a native Android app.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes. There are are good apps which are based on Phonegap and works well in all devices.

2) It depends on what features of the Android you are going to use. Few versions that does not support some features that's available only to new version.

BTW, what is the minimum required version that you have selected for your app? I assume you are developing the app with Android as base version.

When creating a new Android project, you have to set the minimum required platform version. If you set something higher and use the app in a lower version which does not support the feature, results are going to be different.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply to your reply. To answer your question, the minimum SDK version is currently set to 8 (Android 2.3), and I've got things working pretty well on that version. It's actually Android 4.0 that is (by far) the most problematic. Anything above or below 4.0 seems to work okay now, but it's a nightmare every time I try to add something new… I believe part of the problem is that I didn't use a mobile framework (Sencha, JQM, etc.). My app is just a standard, Backbone.js app with mobile styling.